# Set random string variable in laravel InfyOm

Tags: laravel, variables, infyom

Hi i use InfyOm (Laravel Genrator).
I want set random string to variable key on adding new record, but i dont know how i can do it.

**Keys Controller**

```
public function store(CreatekeysRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $keys = $this->keysRepository->create($input);


    Flash::success('Added');

    return redirect(route('keys.index'));
}
```

i generate string on key model with mutator but key changed always when i edit record.

**Keys model**

```
public function setDomainAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['domain'] = $value;
    $key = $this->attributes['key'] = Str::random(16);
    Flash::success("Key generated for {$value}<br><b>{$key}");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `InfyOm` but I believe you can just use the standard Eloquent events like so:

```php
<?php
// models/Key.php
class Key
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function($model) {
            $model->key = Str::random(16);
        });
    }
}
```

The above code will set the `key` property when you're creating a new Key model.

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events